# how to access properties of component without inheritance

Tags: angular, typescript

i need to edit some property of components after login. for example I need to edit message property of HomeComponent and age property of UserComponent so inherit the component class is not an option. How can I achieve this

auth.service

```
// app/auth.service.ts

import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  lock = new Auth0Lock('asdsd', 'mehmetyeneryilmaz.eu.auth0.com', {});

  constructor() {
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  public logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem. Where are `HomeComponent` and `UserComponent`  If you doubt what's the best solution in this case then use service. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shared service with observables and subscribe to changes:

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';

declare var Auth0Lock: any;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  lock = new Auth0Lock('asdsd', 'mehmetyeneryilmaz.eu.auth0.com', {});

  private message = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  public $message = this.message.asObservable(); 

  constructor() {
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    this.lock.show();
    this.message.next('checking authentication');
  }

  public authenticated() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  public logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    this.message.next('successfully logged in');
  }
}
```

```
class HomeComponent {
  constructor(auth:Auth) { 
    auth.$message.subscribe(msg => this.message = msg);
  }

}
```

Comment: I added "import { BehaviorSubject,Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';" line at top [ts] Property 'toObservable' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<string>'. do you have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Sorry, should have been `asObservable()` See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service